# Undefined variable: Blocks/product/product.phtml issue

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, undefined-variable

I have a problem with `Magento 1.9.2.4`, I can't figure out how to fix it:

> 2017-07-13T18: 37: 13 + 00: 00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable:
>   _link in /var/www/html/xxxxxxx.it/app/design/frontend/intenso/petmuffin/template/aw_autorelated/
>   Blocks/product/product.phtml on line 55

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

> This Happens when you try to use a variable that wasn't previously
>   defined !

Go to : `app/design/frontend/intenso/petmuffin/template/aw_autorelated/Blocks/product/product.phtml` then you will find some variable not defined, define it and the message disappears.

**Exemple :**

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // ...
    $iterator++;
}

// the correction:

$iterator = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // do something with item
    $iterator++;
}
```